# syntax error in database query with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have the following query. When I execute it I get such error:

```
[http-nio-8090-exec-9] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
[http-nio-8090-exec-9] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 5385
```

I think the problem is in `select CG.codes from CodeGroup CG`, but how do I write this query correctly? I need to get all the `codes` that belong to the `CodeGroup`. The `codes` is a list of `Code`.

```
    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.append("select distinct AI from AppInfo AI ")
            .append("left join fetch AI.plan as PSAP ")
            .append("where PSAP.edType in ( select C from Code C where C.column1= 'XXXX' ")
            .append("and C in (select CG.codes from CodeGroup CG where CG.name = 'YYYY'))");
```

Comment: Are you selecting `AI` column from AppInfo named AS `AI`? (`select distinct AI from AppInfo AI`). So I think `SQL` does not understand which `AI` do you want to use there `join fetch AI.plan`.

Comment: Which columns does table AppInfo have?

Comment: I select entire AppInfo object from the table. The AI has a column with plan's id based on which I get PSAP from PSAP table. The problem with the query started when I add the last append. Before that everything works fine.

Comment: That looks like HQL - but the database doesn't understand HQL, only SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your line `left join fetch AI.plan as PSAP` is wrong. Omit the `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

What i have observed that, Your select query has small problem, It should be like this

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.append("select DISTINCT AI.COLUMN_NAME from AppInfo AI ")
            .append("left join fetch AI.plan as PSAP ")
            .append("where PSAP.edType in ( select C from Code C where C.column1= 'XXXX' ")
            .append("and C in (select CG.codes from CodeGroup CG where CG.name = 'YYYY'))");
```

Because, AI is the alias name of AppInfo table. Distinct will work on specific column.

Comment: Perfect, It's not function it's a keyword. you can use only to get distinct values.